# Rails 5 Nested Attributes not saving find_or_initialize_by method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm sure new in RoR and using Rails 5.0.6 (Ruby 2.3.4p301). Below is problem I'm stuck for the past tons of hours with-

I have two tables- locations (attributes- address) and reviews (attributes- title, duration, positive, negative, location_id). location.rb is the parent model and reviews.rb is the child model.

**Problem:**
The locations_controller.rb is supposed to check if location.address already exists in the database. If yes, the review will save under the same location_id. If the location.address is not present, a new location and review will be created. That's why I'm using the `find_or_initialize_by` method.

The problem is- review is hitting the database, but with nil values for all attributes. (When I remove line 10 and 11 from locations_controller.rb, then it works fine, just doesn't find existing location.address in the database. Problem is, due to line 10 and 11, the review hashes are not passing through and just creating a record with 'nil' as value.)

## app/models/location.rb

```
class Location < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reviews, inverse_of: :location
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :reviews
end
```

## app/models/review.rb

```
class Review < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :location, optional: true
end
```

## app/controllers/locations_controller.rb

```
01 class LocationsController < ApplicationController
02  
03  def new
04    @location = Location.new
05    @location.reviews.build
06  end
07  
08  def create
09    @location = Location.new(location_params)
10    @location = Location.find_or_initialize_by(address: location_params[:address])
11    @location.reviews.build
12    
13    if @location.save
14      flash[:notice] = "Location has been successfully saved"
15      redirect_to location_path(@location)
16    else
17      render 'new'
18    end
19  end
20  
21  def show
22    @location = Location.find(params[:id])
23  end
24
25  private
26  def location_params
27    params.require(:location).permit(:address, reviews_attributes: [:location_id, :id, :title, :duration, :positive, :negative])
28  end
29  
30 end
```

## app/views/locations/new.html.erb

```
<h1>Create a house review</h1>

<%= simple_form_for @location do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :address, label: 'Enter Address', input_html: { id: 'autocomplete', size: 100 }, placeholder: 'E.g. 1 Collins Street, Melbourne, VIC 3000' %>

    <%= f.simple_fields_for :reviews do |e| %>
      <%= e.input :title %>
      <%= e.input :duration %>
      <%= e.input :positive %>
      <%= e.input :negative %>
    <% end %>

  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

## app/views/locations/show.html.erb

```
<h1>Showing selected location</h1>
<p>
  Location: <%= @location.address %>
</p>
<h2>Reviews (<%= @location.reviews.count %>)</h2>
<% if @location.reviews.present? %>
  <% @location.reviews.each do |review| %>
    <ul>
      <h3><%= review.title %></h3>
      <li>Duration: <%= review.duration %></li>
      <li>Positive: <%= review.positive %></li>
      <li>Negative: <%= review.negative %></li>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
There are no reviews for this location.
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change new with create!, below is the explanation:

new will create an object but rails still not init and id for the record, meanwhile create! will create an object and rails will put init an id value to the record. with an initial id for location if you build "child" record like reviews it will get location_id value

```
def create
  @location = Location.create!(location_params)
  @location.reviews.build
  # your other code
end
```

#### Edit 2, i checked [find_or_initialize_by will be deprecated](https://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/620-rails-find-or-initialize-and-find-or-create-methods-are-deprecated), I think you need to change the logic, here some of idea

```
def create
  @location = Location.find_by_address(location_params[:address])
  if @location.nil?
    # if nil then it's meaning @location was not found in db
    # then you create it with initial id
    @location = Location.create!(location_params)
    # @location will get address from params automatically
  end
  @location.reviews.build
end
```

Comment: I just attempted create! instead of new, still getting the same result sorry. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I just removed line 10, see sample above, I think it's nil because line 10

Comment: Hi @widjajayd, if we remove line 10 which is find_or_initialize_by method, how do we see if the params match with location.address?

Comment: Thanks for #edit 2. I eventually used the .nil? method and changed my logic. It's working now :)

Comment: what if you are trying to create for a `current_user.create_profile(profile_params)`? who would I go about doing the `create` method?